# How to overload istream to accept input giving like this: (5, 6, 7)

Tags: overloading, istream

I have very little code other than code I use to test. I think this is the way to begin:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& os, Vect3D& in)
{
is >>  in.x >> in.y >>  in.z;
return is;

}
```

Testing code:

```
cout << "Testing overload of >> operator" << endl;
stringstream stringin("(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)");
stringin >> v;
cout << v << endl;
cout << "Should be:" << endl;
Vect3D vCorrect(1.5, 2.5, 3.5);
cout << vCorrect << endl << endl;

cout << "Testing chaining of overload of >> operator" << endl;
stringstream sin("(2, 3, 4) 5.9");
double x;
sin >> v >> x;
cout << v << " and " << x << endl;
cout << "Should be:" << endl;
cout << "(2, 3, 4) and 5.9" << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Any ideas? I need to find a way to have it ignore ( , and the space, but I have no idea where to start.  There has to be a way to do this.  I thought i could read it into a string, but i also need to be able to use decimals in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that look problematic here. The overloaded operator function takes in a istream reference named 'os' but in the block you use 'is'. Also, to pipe from input streams to ints and doubles variables they are separated by spaces so your extra '(' and ',' are likely causing a problem as well.